# mention slack users in prometheus alertmanager notification

Tags: prometheus, slack, prometheus-alertmanager

So I have a common label `opsteam` that is supposed to bring DM in slack once alertmanager is fired. However inside slack I get usernames as pure text, not highlighted and these users are not getting any messages.

```
nodeSelector: 
  prometheus: "true"
enabled: true
retention: "30d"
extraFlags:
  - web.enable-lifecycle
  - web.enable-admin-api
strategy:
  type: RollingUpdate
global:
  scrape_interval: 30s
  external_labels:
    env: prod
    client: client
    cluster: project-prod-eks
    opsteam: "@U0325FRAD @U01GN7KJHU"
```

If I change `opsteam: "@U0325FRAD @U01GN7KJHU"` to `opsteam: "@john @jim"` it does no effects either.

so this is my custom slack notification

```yaml
 notifications.tmpl: |          
  {{ define "__alert_silence_link" -}}
      {{ .ExternalURL }}/#/silences/new?filter=%7B
      {{- range .CommonLabels.SortedPairs -}}
          {{- if ne .Name "alertname" -}}
              {{- .Name }}%3D"{{- .Value -}}"%2C%20
          {{- end -}}
      {{- end -}}
      alertname%3D"{{- .CommonLabels.alertname -}}"%7D
  {{- end }}
  
  {{ define "__alert_severity" -}}
      {{- if eq .CommonLabels.severity "critical" -}}
      *Severity:* `Critical` {{ if eq .Status "firing" }}:fire:{{- else -}}:ok:{{- end -}}
      {{- else if eq .CommonLabels.severity "warning" -}}
      *Severity:* `Warning`
      {{- else if eq .CommonLabels.severity "info" -}}
      *Severity:* `Info`
      {{- else -}}
      *Severity:* :question: {{ .CommonLabels.severity }}
      {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
  
  {{ define "__alert_client_details" -}}
      *Env:*     {{ .CommonLabels.env }}
      *Client:*  {{ .CommonLabels.client }}
      *Cluster:* {{ .CommonLabels.cluster }}
  {{- end }}
  
  {{ define "slack.title" -}}
      [{{ .Status | toUpper -}}
      {{ if eq .Status "firing" }}:{{ .Alerts.Firing | len }}{{- end -}}
      ] {{ .CommonLabels.cluster }} - {{ .CommonLabels.alertname }}
  {{- end }}
  
  {{ define "slack.text" -}}
     {{ .CommonLabels.opsteam }}  <<-----------------WANT THEM TO BE User Mentions!!!!!
     {{ template "__alert_severity" . }}
     {{ template "__alert_client_details" . }}
     {{- if (index .Alerts 0).Annotations.summary }}
     {{- "\n" -}}
     *Summary:* {{ (index .Alerts 0).Annotations.summary }}
     {{- end }}
     
     {{ range .Alerts }}      
       {{- if .Annotations.description }}                   
       {{ .Annotations.description }}{{- "\n" -}}
       {{- end }}
       {{- if .Annotations.message }}
       {{ .Annotations.message }}{{- "\n" -}}
       {{- end }}
     {{- end }}
  
  {{- end }}
  
  {{ define "slack.color" -}}
      {{ if eq .Status "firing" -}}
          {{ if eq .CommonLabels.severity "warning" -}}
              warning
          {{- else if eq .CommonLabels.severity "critical" -}}
              danger
          {{- else -}}
              #439FE0
          {{- end -}}
      {{ else -}}
      good
      {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
```

Yes my messages are just text in slack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a given format to embed usernames in Slack.
**https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting#mentioning-users**

> **<@userId>**